# Jhipster issue with Docker environment on Mac OSx during development

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, jhipster, consul

Currently, we are developing a new application using jhipsters microservice approach.
The architecture consists of a uaa server, a gateway, consul as service registry, and several microservices.

If we deploy everything in docker containers and run the application completely inside docker it works great. But here's the problem:

We develop on mac OS as host machines using Docker Desktop for Mac. What we want to achieve is, that we can run 98% of our infrastructure inside docker using a docker-compose file and only run the microservice we are currently working on on the host machine. Consul and the gateway is running inside docker containers as well and all the services registered on consul can be seen on the local mapped port `8500` under `/services` section. The problem we are facing now is, that all the services inside docker (including the uaa server) are registered using the internal docker IP range `172.18.0.x.`. So once our microservice (running on the host machine) for example requests the uaa service using consul it gets `172.18.0.11:9999` as service address. But how can our microservice now access this address from the host machine as there's no bridge available between the two networks (`192.168.101.x` and `172.18.0.x`)

How do you guys use docker when working with jhipster on mac for development? What we've found out so far is, that this problem could be related to docker Desktop for mac, as on Linux, the internal IP is reachable from the host system (so you could, for example, ping `172.18.0.5` from the host system, which doesn't work on mac).

We would be very thankful for any recommendation, as at the moment we can not really benefit from the docker approach and it slows things down instead of improving them.

Thanks in advance,
Florian